# Using a for() loop after array_filter() gives Warning: Undefined array key

Tags: php, arrays, loops, key, filtering

I'm using array_filter with multiple parameters but it's not doing the filter correctly. Here where it's supposed to return an array with only "arts,crafts,designs" as an element, it's returning an empty array. The only $askedcat parameter it works for is "arts". I can't find out what the issue is.

I've tried not using an array_filter and instead just looping over the array, and I get the same problem.

```
class CategoryFilter {
    public $categoryAskedFor;

    function __construct($askedCat) {
            $this->categoryAskedFor = $askedCat;
    }

    function categoryCallback($projectCategoryString) {
        $project_category_array = explode(",", $projectCategoryString);
        if(in_array($this->categoryAskedFor, $project_category_array)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}

$verifiedProjects = ["arts", "arts,crafts,designs", "film", "film,theater"];

$askedCat = "crafts";

$newArr = array_filter($verifiedProjects, array(new CategoryFilter($askedCat), "categoryCallback"));

for ($i = 0; $i < count($newArr); $i++) {
    echo $newArr[$i] . "<br>";
}
```

I expect the output here to be `arts,crafts,design<br>` but it's only `<br>` meaning the array is empty.

Comment: `$this->categoryAskedFor` instead of `$this->$categoryAskedFor` in `__construct`…!?

Comment: What @deceze said plus the fact that you're looping over your array wrong. Use `foreach` (`array_filter` will preserve keys so the 0 index is not necessarily there after filtering).

Comment: Please go enable proper PHP error reporting. (Go read up on it, if you don’t know what that means.) PHP could alert you to a lot of these issues on its own already, before you need to go bother someone else with them.

Comment: Edited above @deceze wasn't my issue, just happened when I copied the code over here

Comment: @Jeto are you referencing the loop that prints the values?

Comment: Yes, they are. Use `var_dump($newArr);` instead of any loops, then you should be able to spot what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're looping over your resulting array is wrong, because `array_filter` will preserve the array keys. The 0 index may not be there in the filtered version (and in your case, it actually isn't).

Use `foreach` instead:

```
foreach ($newArr as $value) {
  echo $value, '<br>';
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `echo $value . '<br>';`

Comment: @Claudio Nope, `echo` takes any number of parameters, this way you don't have to build/buffer a string before outputting it.

Comment: Great, didn't knew that

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to achieve this but let me show you two way here

WAY #1

If you using the `for` loop to retrieve the array value then need to have numeric key and as per your code you need `array_values` function to manage that

```
<?php

    class CategoryFilter {
        public $categoryAskedFor;

        function __construct($askedCat) {
                $this->categoryAskedFor = $askedCat;
        }

        function categoryCallback($projectCategoryString) {
            $project_category_array = explode(",", $projectCategoryString);
            if(in_array($this->categoryAskedFor, $project_category_array)) return true;
            return false;
        }
    }

    $verifiedProjects = ["arts", "arts,crafts,designs", "film", "film,theater"];

    $askedCat = "crafts";

    $newArr = array_filter($verifiedProjects, array(new CategoryFilter($askedCat), "categoryCallback"));

    $newArr = array_values($newArr);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($newArr); $i++) {
        echo $newArr[$i] . "<br>";
    }
```

WAY # 2

If you don't want to use the `array_values` here then you need to manage the `foreach` loop instead of `for` loop

```
<?php

    class CategoryFilter {
        public $categoryAskedFor;

        function __construct($askedCat) {
                $this->categoryAskedFor = $askedCat;
        }

        function categoryCallback($projectCategoryString) {
            $project_category_array = explode(",", $projectCategoryString);
            if(in_array($this->categoryAskedFor, $project_category_array)) return true;
            return false;
        }
    }

    $verifiedProjects = ["arts", "arts,crafts,designs", "film", "film,theater"];

    $askedCat = "crafts";

    $newArr = array_filter($verifiedProjects, array(new CategoryFilter($askedCat), "categoryCallback"));

    foreach ($newArr as $value) {
        echo $value . "<br>";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

array_filter will remove elements but will not reset the keys. use array_values to reset the keys first.

```
$newArr = array_values($newArr);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($newArr); $i++) {
    echo $newArr[$i] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, while foreach solved the issue, this is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You will get as per your output

```
$askedCat = 'crafts';
$verifiedProjects = ["arts", "arts,crafts,designs", "film", "film,theater"];
$newArr = array_filter($verifiedProjects, function ($item) use ($askedCat) {
    if (stripos($item, $askedCat) !== false) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

foreach ($newArr as $value) {
        echo $value . "<br>";
    }
```